# Checking out code from github into netbeans/ecplise

Tags: java, netbeans, github

It is the first time i am trying to checkout someone else code from github.

I have downloaded the jar

```
https://github.com/wittawatj/jtcc
```

However, there is only a `src` folder which i am unsure of how to insert it into netbeans or ecplise without having to rename all the packages and classes.

I believe there is some shorter way.

I would like to edit the Java code like its my own source code where I could make some tweaks to it

Comment: Don't know if its a library, but you can import the jar through the Libraries in the project in the project list. And then right click on Libraries and select add jar/folder

Comment: donno how to do it it netbeans but in eclipse, you just need to use build.xml

Comment: Any steps that I can follow? I can't seem to find much material online that works and yet it doesn't seem to make sense that it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NetBeans you can directly clone the source repository from within NetBeans:

Use Team -> Git -> Close to checkout the source code from GitHub and supply the necessary information in the following dialog:

[image]

In the final page of the wizard you can enable the "Scan for NetBeans project" option:

[image]

As the project does not contain a NetBeans project, NetBeans will prompt you to create a new project after the code has been downloaded:

[image]

Use the option "Java Project with existing sources" to setup the NetBeans project with the sources from GitHub.

[image]

Details on setting up a project in NetBeans can be found in the manual: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#BABCGJJB

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried it on my machine with `git clone https://github.com/wittawatj/jtcc` and everything got downloaded, are you sure you are using the right git commands?

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: except i dont have 50 reputation and can't post one so StackOverflow decided for me..

Comment: Yes I am able to download the zip file but I wanna change the code inside the source but not using it as a wholesale jar